# Difference between guard and event in UML state diagram

Tags: uml, diagram, staruml, argouml

I thought I could differentiate between **event** and **guard**. But I came across an event being similar to guard:

```
counter > 4 [pin is high] / switch on
^^^^^^^^^^^ 
   event
```

where I viewed the variable counter changes from some value smaller than 4 to that greater than 4 as event. Does that mean event can also be a condition like guard?

Answer (score 2):

An **event** is the thing that triggers the transition. In your case `counter > 4` is a change event, meaning "*the counter value has changed and its value is now greater than 4*".

The code between the brackets is the **guard**. In your case `pin is high`, meaning "*the transition is only enabled if the pin is high*".

`switch on` is the **behavior** that is executed when the transition is executed.

Footnote: In your example the event is indeed very similar to the guard.

In C it could look like that:

```c
/** 
 * this interrupt is triggered when the
 * counter exceeds the threshold (4)
 */
static void counter_isr(void)
{
   if (pin_is_high(PIN))
       switch_on();
}
```

**From the UML 2.5 specification:**

> **14.2.3.8 Transitions**
>   ...
>   A Transition may own a set of Triggers, each of which specifies an Event
>   whose occurrence, when dispatched, may trigger traversal of the
>   Transition. A Transition trigger is said to be enabled if the dispatched
>   Event occurrence matches its Event type.
>
> **14.2.4.9 Transition** ...
>   The default textual notation for a Transition is defined by
>   the following BNF expression:
>
> ```
> [<trigger> [‘,’ <trigger>]* [‘[‘ <guard>’]’] [‘/’ <behavior-expression>]]
> ```

In other words: `trigger [guard] / behavior`