# How to set a class operation call as transition in an UML state machine diagram? (Sparx EA)

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

Is it possible to reuse an operation call of a class as transition in an UML diagram of Sparx Enterprise Architect (I've got version 9)? If yes, how do I do that?

It's possible to use it as action in an activity diagram and as message in an object diagram, but I can't figure it out for the state machine. I wish there was more integration for software developers...

Furthermore, I wish I could set a state in the diagram as special state of a class instance (class instance == object).

Comment: "message in an object diagram"? Do you mean sequence diagram? I have never seen messages in object diagrams.

Comment: I don't understand the sentence about "special state of a class instance". Could you clarify please?

Comment: I want to demonstrate via UML how a programmed state machine for a handshake transfer protocol works. The states are actually variable values in the source code of certain C++-objects which are instances of C++-classes. The transitions are the member functions of the classes which leads to such new states. I want to be tide to the code, and want to reuse the class member functions which were scanned from the source code.

Comment: On object diagram can have directed associations between objects where I can add a message to it which can be defined as certain operation-call of a C++ class member function. This way an object diagram is quite similar to a sequence diagram but doesn't have a timeline.

Comment: Do you mean [communication diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_diagram)?

Comment: [UML Protocol State Machine Diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/protocol-state-machine-diagrams.html)

Comment: @sergej: Not communication diagram, this one: http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_objectdiagram.html

Comment: And what are the messages in these diagrams?

Comment: @sergej: The association lines between the objects can be set to be a "message". Look here: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=325a7cb and http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=641a410

Comment: You can double-click the message and select the operation in the "message" menu. But such diagrams are commonly called communication (not object) diagrams.

Comment: @sergej: in Sparx EA, a communication diagram type is just a subset of an object diagram type with reduced functionality. But generally you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to reuse an operation call of a class as transition in an UML diagram ...?

Yes. In the state machine diagram: 
Open the transition properties, enable "Effect is Behavior" and 
select the operation from the browser.

[image]

> It's possible to use it as action in an activity diagram ...

Yes. Add a *'Call Operation'* action to the activity diagram.
Goto, "action properties" -> "Call" and select the operation from the
"Behavior:" menu.

[image]

> ... and as message in an object diagram ...

Yes. Draw a *link* between the objects on the object diagram,
right-click the link and select "Add message from ... " (where "..." is the desired direction). Double-click the message and select the operation from the
"Message:" drop-down list.

[image]

Comment: Great! Do you also know how to show in the diagram how the operation-call leads to a new state where a certain attribute has a certain new value?

Comment: @falkb The question is not clear to me. Shall the operation be executed during transition or shall the transition be triggered by the operation?

Comment: That's the same for me. The reason for a new state is why a certain operation (C-function) was called in the program (maybe with a special parameter value). The state is usually stored in certain variables, e.g. flags will be set or a enum-typed state-variable is set to a new value.

Comment: Not my expertise, but the point in time is determined by entry/exit/do (stereotypes).

Comment: @falkb *Transition-behavior* and *Transition-trigger* are two different things in UML state machines, it's not the same. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32404829/2020827).

Comment: Do you know how to display values of attributes (of objects) as they define the new state after a transition?

Comment: Aaah, got it by myself! Context menu on a state in the state machine diagram -> click on "attributes..." -> browse and choose 'type' from model tree, and set name and initial value. Now that's it. :-)