# How define external function call within a guard of state machine in EA

Tags: uml, state-machine, enterprise-architect

As a follow up topic of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33563076/how-to-set-a-class-operation-call-as-transition-in-an-uml-state-machine-diagram) question , I would like to use a external function call of a class ( bool MyClas:: myFunc()) in order to evaluate a guard in EA. Is it possible to do this? This topic showed me how to assign external actions and function calls to the Effect field. I would also like to do it for the Guard field

The reason behind is that I want to separate the logic regarding the state machine (" go from state A to state B ") from the logic regarding the transitions ( here I want to write manual code for each guard implementation).

Answer (score 1):

You can not evaluate a method's return value as guard. You can only set the behavior of a transition to some method since the guard itself is plain text:

[image]

You could use some naming convention, though.

Also you can consider using a trigger like this:

[image]

Still, this is not a result from a function.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I thought so, because I´have browsed the possibilities for about oen hour than I quit. I am now facing similar problem where I need to have the transitions evaluated in the order of defined priority. Such feature seems also to lack EA..

Comment: I have been thinking about it and maybe the edit shows an alternative.